# WordPress: Why Customizer options changed in Divi theme without any reason?

Tags: wordpress

My tabs in Customizer suddenly changed for no reason.

Here's a snip:

[image: Tabs image]

The tabs should be Site Identity, Additional CSS, etc.

As I'm new to WordPress, I must have clicked something I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Your customizer may change when you install new plugins or update your theme. This is normal.

Comment: So how do I get it back?